# textarea sets content of iframe - security with CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, html, security, codemirror

I'm using CodeMirror to make a project similar to JSFiddle. Referencing [this example file](https://codemirror.net/demo/preview.html) from CodeMirror, I'm rendering full HTML content from a textarea (including script tags from external javascript files).

It's all working well locally, but before deploying, isn't there a security threat to rendering a full HTML page from user-defined input? How is the example above not a security threat?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a security issue if you execute user-defined input inside on your application domain.

For example, 
1) JS Bin executes user code on a different domain.
The given code will make it clear. `alert(document.URL)`
https://jsbin.com/xezusur/edit?html,js,output

2) Even, JS Fiddle executes code in an iframe on a different URL
https://jsfiddle.net/djadmin/zrks3reg/

As you can see in both the examples given above, the user code is executed on a different domain. Thus, it prevents user input from accessing resources on different domain due to Same Origin Policy.